# Lock icons on Nexus 5

Tags: nexus-5, app-icons

App icons are deleted or getting moved to other screens by mistake. Is there any app to lock the icons? I don't want to install a launcher if I can get an app to lock the icons.

Comment: In short, apps can't control other apps. This means you have to use a different launcher that has the feature... But... If you have root, there is Xposed Framework. It allows you to install modules that modify the application code as it is run allowing all sorts of customization. There is a module called [Xposed Gel Settings](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2647275) that provides customization options to the stock Google Now launcher. It doesn't let you lock icons now, but maybe you could request the feature. That is as close as you will come without a different launcher.

Comment: Thank you for the response..i will have to think of a launcher than rooting it now.

Answer (score 0):

I agree it would be nice if Android were to lock down its app icons because they're too easy to accidentally move/remove! Ugh, so annoying! While Apple iOS also doesn't lock down their app icons, it's actually harder to accidentally move/remove app icons than on Android.

Sorry this doesn't exactly answer your question because it doesn't involve an add-on app to preexisting launcher but, there's a very thoughtfully designed, lightweight launcher called Smart Launcher that has an important feature called "Prevent Modifications," which solves the problem of accidental moving/deletion of app icons you and most people are having.

Other unique benefits/features:

1. Conserves screen real estate by allowing two actions per icon/app--secondary action done by double-pressing an icon/app; allowed actions include app, folder, widget, shortcut, etc.
2. Arranges home screen apps into a circular (other choices as well) pattern, making it easy for user to remember where things are, so access is faster.
3. Instead of showing apps collection page by page, it groups apps by their categories, modifiable by user. It's like the Linux Mint Operating System's start or app menu.
4. Rarely used apps can be hidden by user.
5. Since it's among the most lightweight of all launchers, it conserves battery and valuable resources which could be used for something else, which is crucial for slower, older phones.
6. Advertised to work with "OK Google" voice command, though I've never tried it because I don't need it. Uses a Contacts-searchable bar on the homescreen.
7. Doesn't require rooting.
8. I've been happily using the Free version which meets my needs, but if you find you like the additional features then they're in the Pro version.

Comment: Link for the app?